# Windows Phone 8 UnauthorizedAccessException when opening file

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, file-access

I am having a very strange error when trying to access a ".stl" file in the "Stl" folder of my application when the app is downloaded from the Windows Phone Marketplace. It does not exhibit this behavior when it is launched from Visual Studio 2012 Express in either debug or release mode. Once I try loading a file it gives me an "**System.UnauthorizedAccessException** Access to path '**C:\Data\Programs\APPUID\Install\Stl\test.stl**' is denied" exception while accessing a ".gcode" file in an almost exactly the same fashion from the "**GCode**" causes no error what so ever.

I have no idea what could be causing this or how to debug this because I don't know if I can somehow attach the debugger to an instance of the store downloaded app.

I also have no idea what could possibly be different between deploying the exact same app from the store and from Visual Studio. The Visual Studio installed app also does not give any troubles if the app is launched from the phone without the debugger being attached.

Any ideas?

PS. The file is being opened by a filestream which is then used by a binarreader. I am not sure if the source code is really needed and for which part but the important line is just:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
```

Where "filePath" in this case is "Stl\test.stl".

Comment: try to run vs in administration mode, or assign access permissions to the folder you mentioned.

Comment: @akbarali Sorry could you just elaborate on what you want me to do because I am struggling to understand.

Comment: the path that you mentioned, go to that folder, open properties then in security tab assign full control, click apply, then run the app.

Comment: I am sorry but how exactly should I do that as Windows Phone does not have a file explorer?

Comment: did you check temp folder , search there the folder name, and assign permissions. go to run and type %temp%

Comment: @akbarali I am very sorry If I am being ignorant here but you do realize the question relates to a "Windows Phone" application as in xap package not function correctly, not a "Windows" application?

Comment: What's the full name of the file your accessing? What's the contents of the file? How are you accessing the file (show code)?

Comment: I have now added some code but I doubt it's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. The "install" directory is actually restricted access but for some reason the Visual Studio signing process leaves the app with enough permissions to access this folder. The correct procedure of determining a relative directory is not to use "Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()" but rather to use "ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder". Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your actual code it is hard to say what the problem is. So instead of attempting to read your mind I will offer an alternative solution.

I have worked extensively with Isolated Storage on the Windows Phone and I have learned this.

There is no library, no API, no SDK, no Web service, in the world, that has worse error reporting than the Isolated Storage on windows phone.

EVERYTHING is Invalid Access or Unauthorized Access with ZERO further information.

To remedy this I created a DLL that serializes objects to the Isolated Storage for you.

All you have to do is put `[DataContractAttribute]` above your class name and `[DataMemeber]` above any variable you want saved. Then you just pass your object and unique name into the savefile method. That's it! Instant save

You can find my free DLL EZ_Iso.dll for [download here](http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=47). With example code and instructions

The code is open source so if you wish you may also decompile the dll and see how it all works.

Feel free to reach out to me here or on twitter if you have any questions or enhancements.

Comment: I agree on the Error Handling, usually it's a threading issue (two threads touching the same file) when I get that error

Comment: Hi Anthony - the link is broken - could you please fix it if you still have the files? Thank you

Comment: @user3141326 Hey, thanks for taking a look at it. I recently rebuilt my server so those assets don't exist on there anymore. I would be happy to re-post it this week however, this was written two years ago. I'm not sure if it even works anymore.

Comment: Sure - please share when you have the chance - no warranties =). At least would help me understand possible issues by looking at source. Thank you